# JQGrid 4.8.2 TopPager not displaying Page Counts

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using JQGrid 4.8.2 and am having trouble with the display of the top pager.

```
var utGrid = $("#userTaskListGrid");
utGrid.jqGrid({
    url: loadingUrl, //Load JQGrid Data
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: colNames,
    colModel: colModel,
    pager: "#pager",
    rowNum: 25,
    rowList: [25, 50, 75, 100],
    sortname: "1",
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewRecords: true,
    gridview: false,
    caption: "User Task List",
    multiselect: true,
    ignoreCase: true,
    loadtext: "Please hold, Loading Data...",
    loadui: "block",
    loadonce: false,
    toppager: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    rownumWidth: 25
});
```

The bottom pager displays everything correctly, but the top pager does not.

On the bottom pager I see "Page 1 of 37" while on the top pager I only see "Page 1 of "

The following images are what I see in developer tools.

[image: Top Pager Image]
[image: Bottom Pager Image]

As you can see, the sp_1_pager_toppager span simply does not have the value.

If you have any recommendations on how to resolve this, please assist!

Thanks!

Comment: Should I simply copy the contents from sp_1_pager to sp_1_pager_toppager?

Comment: You can just try whether you have any problem if you would use free jqGrid 4.9.1 instead. You can just change URLs see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). If you would have some problems with free jqGrid too, I could sure help you. In any way you should include `colModel` which you use. The `name` properties of `colModel` will be used to build some ids. So wrong vales for `name` properties could follows very strange effects. You use `sortname: "1"` which looks *very suspected*.

Comment: I have an extensive set of columns in which I trap in the colModels variable. My indexes are set to numerical as opposed to the names of the fields solely for sorting purposes. All of this works fine. Today I decided to use a top pager, and the only fault I am seeing is the total page value is not being set in toppager. I will try to use free jqgrid 4.9.1 to see if that fixes this issue.

Comment: Thank you @Oleg, switching to free jqGrid 4.9 solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there are a bug in jqGrid 4.8.2, probably it exists in combination with ids which you use. You can just try whether you have any problem if you would use free jqGrid 4.9.1 instead. You can just change URLs see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) is the fork of jqGrid which I develop. So if you would have some problems with free jqGrid, I could sure help you.